# Why Lumen send the response with headers into the body?

Tags: http-headers, httpresponse, lumen

When I call Lumen, it's always return the header with the response no matter the method. Why?

Here is the router :

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'test'], function() use ($router) {

    $router->post('an', 'MyController@anAction');
});
```

This is an action from my controller

```
public function anAction(Request $request): string {

    $return['result'] = true;
    return response()->json($return);
}
```

And this is the response :

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type: application/json Date: Thu, 02 May 2019 14:54:35 GMT {"result":true}
```

How can I just have this?

```
{"result":true}
```

Comment: What does your middleware look like?

Comment: I don't use any middleware, there is only the authenticate.php in this folder from the installation.

Comment: It could also be your web server sending the header information, e.g. Apache

Comment: It would be surprising. For another project I use Slim (symfony) in a restfull API running on the same environment and I don’t have this behavior.

Comment: Also, it work fine when i use `return json_encode($return);` instead of `return response()->json($return);`. So what's wrong with the `Response` object?

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: It's running with xampp on local and I do test via another project with `Zend_Http_Client()` or **RESTer** plugin on my browser, same result with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this issue, was caused by the typehint return on the function:

```php
public function anAction(Request $request): string {
```

That was converting the response to a string rather than the Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse it actually is. Changing it to this solved my issue.

```php
public function anAction(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse {
```